# Android app crashes , caused is the iterator

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, iterator

I have a list called listOfDrills which has Iterator drillIt, some why the iterator has no `next()` value (I am sore the list is not empty because it works fine with `listOfDrills.get(0)`). Here is the code:

```
package com.simplemathgame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GamePlayActivity extends Activity {
    int addDrills;
    int subDrills;
    int mulDrills;
    int divDrills;
    int minBound;
    int maxBound;

    TextView drillTextPlace;
    Button nextButton;
    Button backButton;

    List<Drill> listOfDrills = new ArrayList<Drill>();
    Iterator<Drill> drillIt = listOfDrills.iterator();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_play);

        //get values from other activity
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        addDrills = extras.getInt("addDrills");
        subDrills = extras.getInt("subDrils");
        mulDrills = extras.getInt("mulDrills");
        divDrills = extras.getInt("divDrills");
        minBound = extras.getInt("minBound");
        maxBound = extras.getInt("maxBound");

        for(int i = 0; i < addDrills; i++){
            AddDrill tmpDrill = new AddDrill(minBound,maxBound);
            listOfDrills.add(tmpDrill);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < subDrills; i++){
            SubDrill tmpDrill = new SubDrill(minBound,maxBound);
            listOfDrills.add(tmpDrill);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < mulDrills; i++){
            MulDrill tmpDrill = new MulDrill(minBound,maxBound);
            listOfDrills.add(tmpDrill);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < divDrills; i++){
            DivDrill tmpDrill = new DivDrill(minBound,maxBound);
            listOfDrills.add(tmpDrill);
        }

        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(listOfDrills, new Random(seed));

        drillTextPlace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drill_text);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);

        if(drillIt.hasNext()){
            drillTextPlace.setText((drillIt.next()).printDrill());
        }

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(drillIt.hasNext()){
                    drillTextPlace.setText(drillIt.next().printDrill());
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The code never enters in:

```
if(drillIt.hasNext()){
            drillTextPlace.setText((drillIt.next()).printDrill());
        }
```

and if I remove the `if` statement and leave only  `drillTextPlace.setText((drillIt.next()).printDrill());`
the app crashes.

Why this is happening? What did I do wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: What error message do you get? Show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create the iterator after you have filled the list. As seen in the documentation:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Move

```
Iterator<Drill> drillIt = listOfDrills.iterator();
```

to just before:

```
if (drillIt.hasNext()) {
    drillTextPlace.setText((drillIt.next()).printDrill());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the iterator too early,  need to create it just before you want to use it. You are creating it when it is empty. Even if that worked each time you call next you will step forward and never step back...